# Can I use variable in redirection function?

Tags: codeigniter

Can I use codeigniter redirects function contains variable name like this?

```
redirect($page_url);
```

I have page url in a session variable so, im saving session in codeigniter varible

```
      $page_url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $page_url=explode("/", $page_url, 3);
      $data = array('page_url'=>$page_url[2],'validated' => true);
      $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that ?

Comment: yes. actually am sending mail alert to user, from mail when user clicks page link, am saving page url in session varibale and redirects to login page, so when user logins if session variable of url present i am redirecting to that url

Comment: what is the problem you got for that. Obviously you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use variables surely but make sure you are loading URL helper first and checking if the `$page_url` variable is set. For example:

```
$this->load->helper('url');

if(isset($page_url) && $page_url != '') {
  redirect($page_url);
} else {
  redirect('/index.php');
}
```